# wxPython: Is there a way to change the colour of the Scrollbar in a wx.ScrolledWindow?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've found that if I make a `wx.ScrollBar` directly, I can modify its background color via the `SetBackgroundColour()` function. However, I'm unsure of how to reference to Scrollbar when it's part of a `wx.ScrolledWindow`.

How do I get reference to the Scrollbar in a ScrolledWindow?

A second question is this, is there a way to change more than just the Background color on a Scrollbar? I'm attempting to implement a "nighttime" mode, and thus want to mute all the colors a bit. Doing this in the rest of the program was fairly straight forward, but the scrollbars remain a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the reference to each ScrollBar (one horizontal and one vertical) by querying scrolledwindow.GetChildren() like:

```
sw = wx.ScrolledWindow(self)
for child in sw.GetChildren():
  if isinstance(child, wx.ScrollBar):
    print child
    child.SetBackgroundColour(...)
```

Regarding your second question, there's SetForegroundColour(). You can always look through the documentation by doing:

```
python
>>> import wx
>>> help(wx.ScrollBar)
```