# wxpython Changing built-in Scroll Bars (in ScrolledWindow) shape and color

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, wxpython, scrollbar

I want to change  built-in Scroll Bars (in ScrolledWindow) style-shape- from normal style-shape- (windows 7 default Scroll Bars style) to slim Scroll Bar and I want to change it's color to red(or any other color).
But I don't know how to do that.

I tried to change color using the answer here
[wxPython: Is there a way to change the colour of the Scrollbar in a wx.ScrolledWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151659/wxpython-is-there-a-way-to-change-the-colour-of-the-scrollbar-in-a-wx-scrolledw)
But `GetChildren()` Can't find built-in Scroll Bars for me, I don't know why!
So is there any way to do what I want ?